# Exclude fields in Django admin for users other than superuser

Tags: python, django

I have a simple `MyUser` class with `PermissionsMixin`. `user.is_superuser` equals `True` only for superusers. I'd like to be able to do something similar to this in my `admin.py`:

```
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        fieldsets = (
            (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
            ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_admin','is_staff')}),
            ('Place', {'fields': ('place',)}),
            ('Important dates', {'fields': ('last_login',)}),
        )
    else:
        fieldsets = (
            (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
            #('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_admin','is_staff')}),
            ('Place', {'fields': ('place',)}),
            ('Important dates', {'fields': ('last_login',)}),
        )
```

Basically I want my users to be able to create other users, but not give them admin or stuff permissions. Only superusers should be able to do that.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, what you want to do is override the get_form method for the ModelAdmin. Base on [the example from django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/), it would look something like this:

```
class MyUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        self.exclude = []
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            self.exclude.append('Permissions') #here!
        return super(MyUserAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
```

Now you might need to hack around a little and maybe override the save method as well. I did something similar not long ago, it's not so complicated (and the docs are fantastic).

There might be a simpler solution but your question is kinda general and you didn't share your user model, so I can't tell you exactly how to work this out. I hope this helps!

Comment: It's not correct. If someone open admin site with not superuser rights - exclude appends field "Permissions". But when you re-login to admin site as superuser - you can see admin site with excluded field. To solve this problem I use "if ...: ... else: ..." to return changed fields to original state.

Comment: @AntonDanilchenko I actually haven't tested the code, I just showed the general gist of how to make the form be dynamic to the user. The situation you're talking about it is a rare one, because usually a user will either be a superuser *or* a normal user, and won't logout as one then login as another. Nevertheless, nice point, +1

Comment: @alirezasanaee try figuring it out for yourself, search SO for a solution, try solving it again, then when all is lost... try solving it again. Then, if you didn't solve it yet, open up a new question with details about what you tried and didn't manage to solve. Someone (maybe even me) will surly help you out. Good luck! =]

Comment: @yuvi thank you but my problem is that I have my custom users which I implemented it from BaseUser class and it led to implementing admin forms again so seems making changes in django BaseUser bring some limitations in django admin class such as this example , what's your idea ???

Comment: @alirezasanaee that you shouldn't try and solve a problem in the comment section of an already answered question. Open a new one, and add as much relevant details as you can (even if I wanted, your comment tells me nothing about the problem, and I have no idea what you're doing wrong with a theoretical descriptions).

Comment: Its not thread-safe as @AntonDanilchenko said. Use kwargs["exclude"] instead of self.exclude.

Comment: @sstevko or override `get_fields` if you're using Django 1.7 which is a lot better

Answer (score 19):

Accepted answer is close but as others point out, get_form is called multiple times on the same instance of the Admin model and the instance is reused, so you can end up with fields repeated or other users seeing the fields after self.fields is modified. Try this out in Django <=1.6:

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    normaluser_fields = ['field1','field2']
    superuser_fields = ['special_field1','special_field2']

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            self.fields = self.normaluser_fields + self.superuser_fields
        else:
            self.fields = self.normaluser_fields

        return super(MyAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
```

Looks like, Django 1.7 introduces a get_fields() method you can override which is a much nicer approach:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/d450af8a2687ca2e90a8790eb567f9a25ebce85b/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L276

Comment: Nice one @Matt. I would also like to add that appart from the `get_fields` there is also a `get_fieldsets` method. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_fields

Answer (score 10):

Django now has a `get_exclude` method on ModelAdmin for excluding fields programmatically.

It takes the current request and the object (if any) as argument. You can put a check there on the request argument to see if they're a superuser and check

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_exclude(self, request, obj=None):
        excluded = super().get_exclude(request, obj) or [] # get overall excluded fields

        if not request.user.is_superuser: # if user is not a superuser
            return excluded + ['extra_field_to_exclude']

        return excluded # otherwise return the default excluded fields if any
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_form), the correct way is to create a ModelForm for superusers and another for normal users. Then you specify each form in the get_form method of your ModelAdmin:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            kwargs['form'] = MySuperuserForm
        else:
            kwargs['form'] = MyNormalForm
        return super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
```

Comment: The docs say "for example" and not "the correct way". This is misleading and often not even appropriate. Not to mention that this example simply comes from the stone age. As @Matt says there are also `get_fields` and `get_fieldsets` methods available for the matter nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

Starting Django 1.7 you can replace the base class of your model admin with something like:

```
class SuperuserAwareModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    superuser_fields = None
    superuser_fieldsets = None

    def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj = None):
        if request.user.is_superuser and self.superuser_fieldsets:
            return (self.fieldsets or tuple()) + self.superuser_fieldsets
        return super(SuperuserAwareModelAdmin, self).get_fieldsets(request, obj)

    def get_fields(self, request, obj = None):
        if request.user.is_superuser and self.superuser_fields:
            return (self.fields or tuple()) + self.superuser_fields
        return super(SuperuserAwareModelAdmin, self).get_fields(request, obj)
```

Example:

```
class MyModelAdmin(SuperuserAwareModelAdmin):
    superuser_fieldsets = (
        (_('Permissions'), {'fields': ('is_staff', )}),
    )
```

The `SuperuserAwareModelAdmin` base class can also be created as a mixin.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way inspired by previous answers. In my example only a superuser may create a superuser. If it is not superuser the checkbox in the form is missing. It works for me and I hope it is correct:

```
    def get_form(self, form_class=form_class):

        if self.request.user.is_superuser is False:
            self.form_class.base_fields.pop('is_superuser')
        return super(AccountCreateView, self).get_form()
```