# Django hide fields only in CREATE object admin page

Tags: django

As subject, i want to hide some fields ONLY when users enter the 'CREATE' admin page for specific model.

I know that change list_display can hide fields in admin page, but it's a global setting which will take affect not only in 'CREATE' admin page, but also in 'UPDATE' admin page.

Answer (score 3):

```
@admin.register(User)
class UserProfileAdmin(UserAdmin):
    def get_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        fields = super(UserProfileAdmin, self).get_fields(request, obj)
        for field in fields:
            if field == 'some_field_name' and obj is None:
                continue
            yield field
```

Comment: Now i solve it, the function i orverride is get_fieldsets(). Anyway, thx.

Answer (score 2):

Copied from [Exclude fields in Django admin for users other than superuser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19203067/exclude-fields-in-django-admin-for-users-other-than-superuser)

```
def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
    fieldsets = super(MediaAdmin, self).get_fieldsets(request, obj)
    if not obj: 
        fieldsets = (
            (u'other', {
                'fields': ('media_public_id',)
            }),
        )
    return fieldsets
```

Answer (score 1):

Django now has a `get_exclude` method on ModelAdmin for excluding fields programmatically.

It takes the current request and the object (if any) as argument. In your case, the object argument will be none if it's a "create" page so you can use that like so:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_exclude(self, request, obj=None):
        excluded = super().get_exclude(request, obj) or [] # get overall excluded fields

        if not obj: # if it's a create, so no object yet
            return excluded + ['extra_field_to_exclude']

        return excluded # otherwise return the default excluded fields if any
```